# Creating name based user access to certain pages in the nav-bar

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-views, django-templates

I need to create user based access to certain features of my Django web-app .

I have figured out how to restrict access to users that are not super users like so :

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
<a href="{% url 'creditControlHome' %}">Credit Control</a>
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to do this based on names?

For example , " if user.name = George and Bill and Clint " then they can see that part of the nav bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do that. You could have auth [Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#groups) added for a user and then check if the user belongs to that group. For example, in your view, you would add the user to a group like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

user_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='some_group_name') 
user_group.user_set.add(user_obj)
```

Then you can use a custom [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) to check if the current user belongs to a group:

`project_dir/app_name/templatetags/sometag.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Then in your template, you can use this template tag like this:

```
{% load sometag %}

{% if request.user|has_group:"some_group_name" %} 
    <a href='#'>Your Link here</a>
{% endif %}
```

If you don't like the templatetag approach, you could filter the user group in your view as well and use it as a flag to display your items in the template.

If that does not work for you, then you can take a look at [Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).